# Partner WSDL and SObject.getField("FieldName");

Tags: partner-wsdl

The documentation on using the partner WSDL says there's an `SObject.getField("FieldName");` method.  I don't see it.

I saw an example with the two lines that are commented out below.  Those lines will not compile as `SObject` does not have a `getField()` method.

Anyone know how to get field values out of objects returned by the partner API?

```
QueryResult qr = stub.query(soqlQuery);
SObject[] recordList = qr.getRecords();

for (int i = 0; i < recordList.length; i++) {
    SObject contact = recordList[i];
    //Object firstName = contact.getField("FirstName");
    //Object lastName = contact.getField("LastName");   
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the link for the documentation which you are referring in your question? Very recently have been observing quite a few documentation issues, so that may be one of that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not `getField` method but [get(Field)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get_2) method.

Example:

```
Account acc = new account(Name = 'Acme', Description = 'Acme Account');
String description = (String)acc.get(Schema.Account.Description);
System.assertEquals('Acme Account', description);
```

And in your case you are looking for [get(fieldName)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get) method.

Example:

```
Account acc = new account(Name = 'Acme', Description = 'Acme Account');
String description = (String)acc.get('Description');
System.assertEquals('Acme Account', description);
```